# Using math-mode in pgfplots axis unit

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to apply a unit to my axis. Usually I use the `siunitx` package for that. However, this time I would like to use a Greek letter with a subscript `\mu_\text{B}` but my document won't compile.

Here is a MWE which compiles if you remove the `$`s.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbch]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={very thick},
            axis lines = left,
            y unit ={$A$},
            unit marking pre={\text{in }}, 
            unit marking post={},
            ylabel = Yupp
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since  all typesetting of labels occur within math mode, you don't need `$` there. Just use

```
y unit =\mu_{\text{B}},
```

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbch]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis line style={very thick},
            axis lines = left,
            y unit =\mu_{\text{B}},
            unit marking pre={\text{in }},
            unit marking post={},
            ylabel = Yupp
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `y unit =\si{\micro}_{\text{B}},` too if you need.